Combine C++ static libraries into shared library cmake
I have a shared library Main.so that publicly links against couple of open source and other static libraries publicly.
What I want to do is privately link all static libraries to shared library and control what symbols gets exposed and allow headers from these transitive static libraries be consumable by application/library linking against shared library
Is this possible?
Any example would be great
Here is roughly what i want to do
  add_library(Shared SHARED shared.cpp)
  add_library(Static STATIC1 static1.cpp)
  add_library(Static STATIC2 static2.cpp)
  add_library(Static STATIC3 static3.cpp)
  include(GenerateExportHeader)
  generate_export_header(Shared SHARED_NAME MY_SHARED)
  target_link_libraries(Shared PRIVATE Static1 Static2 Static3)
 
  add_executable(app app.cpp)
  # app should be able to use headers/symbols from 
  # STATIC 1,2,3 as they were part of shared 
  # library
  target_link_libraries(app Shared)



If the static libraries weren't compiled using position independent code, then you're out of luck.  What are you gaining from this approach instead of just using static{1,2,3} directly in app?

They are build using position independent code . Main reason is we dont want anyone linking against static {1,2,3} and hide them as internal implementation detail (for the most part)

"What I want to do is privately link all static libraries to shared library" - This is exactly what target_link_libraries(Shared PRIVATE Static1 Static2 Static3) will do in your code. "control what symbols gets exposed" - this part is linker-specific. Consult the documentation of the linker for which linker options you should use. "allow headers from these transitive static libraries be consumable by application/library linking against shared library" - Just write a header which includes headers from your static libraries.
